# Uploading a dataset in winbugs from R

Tags: r, for-loop, winbugs, r2winbugs, winbugs14

I would like to know how to upload a data set from R packages to winbugs.

In particular, "LearnBayes" package in R has too many data sets. I would like to use one of them in Winbugs.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you planning to use a package like `R2WinBUGS` that lets you control winbugs from within R? Or do you need to export the data in a particular format so that you can use Winbugs independently?

Comment: I have started learning winbugs. So how does "R2WinBUGS" works? Currently I want to export the data in r to winbugs.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this [link](https://robertgrantstats.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/exporting-data-from-r-into-winbugss-rs-plus-list-format/) because I have no idea what WinBugs data is suppose to look like but I don't know if it works. It's an R Function that supposedly changes the typical dataset into this list thing and I got the function working but still not able to get the dataset working but I'm really stupid so you might have better luck.